PRUNE LOGFILE PRIOR TO isn't deleting archived log files
DB2 UDB 11.5.7.0
$ db2 get db cfg for PRPT01D | grep  LOGARCH
 First log archive method                 (LOGARCHMETH1) = DISK:/udb/alogs/
 Archive compression for logarchmeth1    (LOGARCHCOMPR1) = OFF
 Options for logarchmeth1                  (LOGARCHOPT1) = 
 Second log archive method                (LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF
 Archive compression for logarchmeth2    (LOGARCHCOMPR2) = OFF
 Options for logarchmeth2                  (LOGARCHOPT2) = 


$ db2 list history backup all for PRPT01D | head

                    List History File for PRPT01D

Number of matching file entries = 1


 Op Obj Timestamp+Sequence Type Dev Earliest Log Current Log  Backup ID
 -- --- ------------------ ---- --- ------------ ------------ --------------
  B  D  20241006050916001   N    D  S0002434.LOG S0002434.LOG                
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ db2 "prune logfile prior to S0002323.LOG"
DB20000I  The PRUNE command completed successfully.

Even after running that command, old log files are still in /udb/alogs/udbinst/PRPT01D/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000.  Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?  Can I just rm those archived log files?

Can't say why PRUNE did not work, but it is absolutely OK to remove the old archived log files manually with rm.
